# Pull particular Excel cell value into Word document using Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA and macros.

I got the repeated task of copy data from Excel and paste it in a particular location in the word document.

**For example, my excel sheet has the data like this:**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID_1 | I'm_One |
| ID_2 | I'm_Two |
| ID_3 | I'm_Three |

**Now i'm looking for a Word macro**

1. Get text in Word table with cell position 3
2. Find the same text in Excel Col1
3. Get the value of Col2 from Excel
4. Paste the value of Col2 in word table with cell position 10
5. Repeat the same process for another table in Word document

[Update]
I have tried with multiple code snippets by google search but unable to construct the working macro.

```
Sub pull_from_Excel2()
    'ref: https://www.macworld.com/article/211753/excelwordvisualbasic.html
    
    Dim Month As String
    
    ID_Range = "A2:A6"     'Select this as range like "A2:A16"
    Offset_to_fetch = 1         'Select this to fetch comments etc. value starts with
    
    Set xlSheet = GetObject("D:\Excel.xlsx")
    
     
    'Snippets:
    'Debug.Print VarType(xlSheet.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A5").Value)
    '8204
    
    Dim Cell As Range, rng As Range
    
    Debug.Print VarType(xlSheet.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ID_Range).Value2)
   
    Set rng = xlSheet.Worksheets(1).Range(ID_Range)
    
    For Each Cell In rng
        Debug.Print Cell.Text
    Next Cell
  
End Sub
```

I used this url to construct my skeleton code: https://www.macworld.com/article/211753/excelwordvisualbasic.html

When i try to get the values from the range of cells in excel, i got the following error for the code.

```
Set rng = xlSheet.Worksheets(1).Range(ID_Range).Value2
```

The above line gives "Object required" error when running.

```
Set rng = xlSheet.Worksheets(1).Range(ID_Range)
```

The above line gives "Type Mismatch" error when running.
Notes: For this error, I tried to use for each loop as this is array but the error is showing before executing the for loop.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for your prompt response. I understood and updated the description with the source code snippet I used and the error I'm facing when I try to get the text. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `cell position 3`, is it a single row/column table ?

Comment: Hi @CDP1802, the `cell position 3` means the cell count in a table where all the cells will be counted as whole but not based on rows or columns. For example, if a table with 2 rows and 3 columns(R2XC3 Matrix), then the location of `cell position 3` is R1XC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use `Option Explicit` and declare all your varibales properly. This way it is less likely that you end up with unseen errors.

> To activate it for all new codes that you add in the future, you can activate it directly in Excel and Word. This is a good practice and will protect you from doing it wrong by notifying you of not declared variables:
>
> In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.
>
> This will add  `Option Explicit` to new modules only. In existing modules `Option Explicit` needs to be added manually as first line.

Further I highly recommend to name your variables according what they contain because otherwise it gets very confusing. You named your variable `xlSheet` but you load a workbook into it and not a worksheet.

The next issue is that your code is in Word and if you declare `rng As Range` then this is of type `Word.Range` and not `Excel.Range` and those are diffetent types so that is why you get a *"Type Mismatch"* error.
To solve this you either go in Word VBA to *Extras* › *Refereces …* and set a reference to the Excel library so you can declare your variable `Dim xlRng As Excel.Range` or if you don't set a reference you declare it as `Object` or `Variant` like in below example:

```
' This code is in Word!

Option Explicit

Public Sub pull_from_Excel2()
    'declare constants
    Const ID_Range As Sting = "A2:A6"     'Select this as range like "A2:A16"
    Const Offset_to_fetch As Long = 1         'Select this to fetch comments etc. value starts with
    
    Dim xlWorkbook As Object
    Set xlWorkbook = GetObject("D:\Excel.xlsx") 'This expects the Excel to be already open! If not open you need to use CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Dim xlRng As Object
    Set xlRng = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(ID_Range)
    
    Dim xlCell As Object
    For Each xlCell In xlRng 
        Debug.Print xlCell.Text
    Next xlCell 
End Sub
```

---

Note if your workbook `Set xlWorkbook = GetObject("D:\Excel.xlsx")` is not open in Excel you need to use `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` and open it.

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim xlWorkbook As Object
Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="D:\Excel.xlsx") 'will open the workbook
xlApp.Visible = True 'make it false to open Excel invisible in the background

'your code here …

'in the end close workbook and Excel (espaciall if you had it invisible!)
xlWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False  
xlApp.Quit 'close Excel
```

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ for the help. It works for me to fetch the cell values.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTables()

    Const XLSX = "D:\Excel.xlsx"

    Dim xlApp, wb, ws
    Dim rngSearch, rngFound
    Dim iLastRow As Long, n As Integer

    ' open spreadsheet
    'Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(XLSX, 1, 1)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(-4162).Row  'xlUp
    Set rngSearch = ws.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)

    ' update tables
    Dim doc As Document, tbl As Table, s As String
    Set doc = ThisDocument
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
         s = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
         s = Left(s, Len(s) - 2)
         Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(s, LookIn:=-4163, LookAt:=1) ' xlValues, xlWhole
         If rngFound Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "'" & s & "' not found in table " & tbl.Title, vbExclamation
         Else
             tbl.Range.Cells(3).Range.Text = rngFound.Offset(0, 1)
             n = n + 1
         End If
    Next

    wb.Close False
    xlApp.Quit
    MsgBox n & " tables updated", vbInformation

End Sub
```