# Read file path in Excel cell to save Word document using Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I use a Word macro to save a Word document to a specific folder as a PDF.

```vb
Sub SaveToPDFinSpecificFolder()
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
  "C:\MyDocuments\Timings\Test\" & Replace(ActiveDocument.Name, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
  ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
  wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
  wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
  CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
  BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

I want to read the file path where I want it saved from an Excel cell.

For example, cell A1 will have the file path I want the Word document saved to.

How would Word read this from the open Excel file and save it there?

Comment: You might want to check out [this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67489997/pull-particular-excel-cell-value-into-word-document-using-word-vba)